# Django custom filter error. Returns "invalid filter"

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to create this custom filter in Django, and I can't for the life of me make it work.

in my templatetags folder I have the files `__init__.py` and `alcextra.py` in my template I first load the static files and then the templatetags. I've tried reseting the server and deleting and creating the files again.

`{% load staticfiles %} {% load alcextra %}`
Which is then extended to my main html file. I have tried putting it in the main html file.

in alcextra.py I have written

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def multiply(value, arg):
    return value * arg
```

I have tried loads of different @register versions like

`@register.filter("multiply", multiply)
@register.filter(name="multiply")
@register.filter()
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True`

And all return the same error, invalid filter: 'multiply'. At this point I don't know what to do or what to try.

[Overview of the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg6mZ.png)

Edit: the template in question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> {% load staticfiles %} {% load alcextra %}
<html>

<head>
  <script src="../../static/javascript/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/alcosearch.css' %}" />
  <title>Alcosearch</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pageheader">
    <h1>Alcosearch</h1>
    <h3>Vinmonopol søk</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

What is annoying is that I tried this in another project and it worked. So I'm not completely sure what I've done or not done.

Edit 2:

The answer is what @Alasdair said. I thought I could load the filter in the template and then use it somewhere else, which was not the case.

Comment: Please show your template.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a [documented feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance) of the Django template language that when you load a custom tag or filter, it is not automatically available in the child template.

You are not using the filter in the base template, so you don't need to load the `alcextra` library there.

Then add the load statement to any child templates that use the filter, for example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load alcextra %}
{% block content %}
{{ my_value|multiply:5 }}
{% endblock content %}
```