# is there a way to set return value to an variable in django

Tags: python, django, function, django-forms, django-templates

I have an custom template tag with something like this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def getLikesByUser(likedFilter, loggedInUserID): 
  likedPeople = likedFilter
  personLoggedIn = loggedInUserID
  for personLiked in likedPeople:
    if personLoggedIn == personLiked.id:
      return True
  return False
```

this will return true or false in my template, is there an option to set this return to an variable in my template?

this is how a call this:

```
{% getLikesByUser Post.likes.filter request.user.id  %}
```

I would like to have this in a variable so I can further check if is true show button if false don't.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) to set variable in django. So, you can do sthg like this:

```
{% load getLikesByUser %}
<body>
    {% with likes_by_user=Post.likes.filter|getLikesByUser:request.user.id %}
    
        {% if likes_by_user %}
            # Do sthg
        {% endif %}

    {% endwith %}
</body>
```

Comment: so when I do it like this: {% with likes_by_user=|getLikesByUser Post.likes.filter request.user.id %}
    
     {% if likes_by_user %}
            # Do sthg
        {% endif %}
Could not find variable at start of |getLikesByUser.
    {% endwith %}.       I get error as

Comment: What is the error?? Note: Not ```{% with likes_by_user=|getLikesByUser Post.likes.filter request.user.id %}```, But this: ``{% with likes_by_user=Post.likes.filter|getLikesByUser:request.user.id %}
``

Comment: even if I use as you show above I get following error: Invalid filter: 'getLikesByUser' I am loading this as {% load custom_template_tag %} where I have getLikesByUser function set as from my original post. Not sure why this error

Comment: Not `{% load custom_template_tag %} `, But this: `{% load getLikesByUser %}`

Comment: once I do that I get 'getLikesByUser' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:....I did restart my server

Comment: Okay. Sorry!!! It is not `{% load getLikesByUser %}` but the name of your filename. If your filename is `getuser_custom_tag.py`, then it would be: `{% load getuser_custom_tag %}`

Comment: correct that's what I am doing and getting this error Invalid filter: 'getLikesByUser'

Comment: Can you follow the question and you have similar situation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554255/django-custom-filter-error-returns-invalid-filter)?